# Virtual methods versus standard default argument

Tags: c++

Imagine the following scenario

```
class B
{
public:
    int n;
    B() { n = 1;};
    virtual int shift() const { return n; }
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    D() { n = 2;};
    int shift() const { return n; }
};

int main()
{
    D d;

    std::cout << d.shift() << std::endl;

    B *b = &d;

    std::cout << b->shift() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

the output is very clear: 2 and 2 due to virtual and the downcasting (base to child).

However, doing some changes in the code like:

```
class B
{
public:
    //int n;
    //B() { n = 1;};
    virtual int shift(int n = 1) const { return n; }
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    //D() { n = 2;};
    int shift(int n = 2) const { return n; }
};
```

and keeping the same main(), we output will be: 2 and 1. Why "1" if the method is virtual ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
std::cout << b->shift() << std::endl;
```

the compiler uses the declaration of the function in class `B` according to the static type of pointer `b` and uses the corresponding default argument.

That is at first the compiler evaluates the argument of the function and this argument is the default argument from declaration

```
virtual int shift(int n = 1) const { return n; }
```

and then uses dynamic binding and calls the function from class `D`.:)

Try the following example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
struct B
{
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual int shift(int n = 1) const { std::cout << "B::shift( int ): "; return n; }
};

struct D : B
{
    virtual int shift(int n = 2) const { std::cout << "D::shift( int ) : "; return n; }
};
    D d;
    B *b = &d;

    std::cout << b->shift() << std::endl;
}
```

and you will get

```
D::shift( int ) : 1
^^^               ^^^
```

That is the compiler searches the name `shift` in the scope of the class `B` according to the static type of pointer `b`. But calls the function from class `D` using the mechanism of the dynamic binding.

Comment: cool .. I got it.. many thanks.. dude we need to pay a clear attention during programming.. I lost some time with this.. many thanks

Comment: @user1657666 when the compiler processes this call b->shift()  he knows nothing about the declaration of the function in class D. It only searches the scope of the class B.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, the compiler is using default parameter values in the mangling of the function name.

The duplicate in the comment above gives another reason. The compiler resolves default parameters at compile time.

Comment: GCC, given `void foo(int = 1) {}`, produces `_Z3fooi`, which means `foo(int)`. I would say it clearly does not use default parameter values in the mangling of the function name.

Comment: @chris, GCC also won't produce the output this program produces.  GCC produces 2 in both cases.

Comment: I obtained this from the GCC 5.2 on Coliru, which produces 2 and 1 respectively. I also took the OP's code for good measure (plus a small change for getting it to actually put `B::shift` in the symbol table) and got `_ZNK1B5shiftEi`, which is `B::shift(int) const` (source: http://demangler.com/)

Comment: @chris, off topic, but demangler.com is a cool link.  thanks.

Comment: Thought a little more about it and had to remove my suggestion that it may be resolved at run time but vtable is suspended. I has to be resolved at compile time because if the declaration doesn't specify the default parameter value, the function call cannot be parsed (it will get parsed as missing a declared mandatory argument).  Which means the declared default value is the one which must be used.